# using wifi and Ethernet at the same time for network camera

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet, webcam, camera

I have a dlink network camera connected to my ARM board (running ubuntu 12.0.4) using a LAN cable. On the other hand, I also have a USB wiif module connected to my pi, which will be connected wirelessly to my access point in my home. Now, the problem is when wifi is active, I am not able to use my camera, and when the camera is active I cannot use wifi. Is there any way of making this work simultaneously , so that I can have the arm board access the camera over ethernet and at the same time be connected to the internet using wifi ?

The static IP I have assigned to my camera is 192.168.1.20, and the static IP I have assigned to my system eth0 is 192.168.1.190 .One more thing is that when my wifi module is connected to the access point, wlan2 IP address shows up as 192.168.1.xx.

Is this same subnet the reason why both wifi and ethernet cannot be used at the same time ?

My /etc/network/interfaces file

```
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.190
   network 192.168.1.1
   broadcast 192.168.1.255
   gateway 192.168.1.1

auto wlan2
iface wlan2 inet dhcp

      wpa-ssid ACT
      wpa-psk 9888888888
```

After booting up, my ifconfig output

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:12634 (12.6 KB)  TX bytes:12634 (12.6 KB)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:e9:84:0c:ad:95
          inet addr:192.168.1.106  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c6e9:84ff:fe0c:ad95/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2398 (2.3 KB)  TX bytes:19785 (19.7 KB)
```

For some reason eth0 doesnt show up, then I enter

```
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.190
```

Now, ifconfig shows :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0a:35:00:01:22
          inet addr:192.168.1.190  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20a:35ff:fe00:122/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4495 (4.4 KB)
          Interrupt:54 Base address:0xb000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:21598 (21.5 KB)  TX bytes:21598 (21.5 KB)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:e9:84:0c:ad:95
          inet addr:192.168.1.106  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c6e9:84ff:fe0c:ad95/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2440 (2.4 KB)  TX bytes:25675 (25.6 KB)
```

route command output

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         WirelessAP      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 wlan2
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

As soon as I enter

```
ifconfig wlan2 down
```

The camera gets detected on the motion software installed.

Comment: Please, post the output of `route` command with both (camera and wifi) connected, thanks.

Comment: @migrc Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         WirelessAP      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 wlan2
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

Comment: I think the problem is that wlan2 and eth0 are the interfaces used to reach 192.168.1.0 network and maybe there is a conflitct here.  Try this: `route del -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev wlan2` (I'm not very sure about the command sintax, but what I'm trying to do is delete the third entry of your route table)

Comment: @migrc After entering this command, camera worked. But, I am not able to connect to the internet via wifi.  ifconfig still shows IP address for both wlan2 and eth0. But I'm not able to connect to the internet. Can you suggest me on how to solve this ? Is it because that both eth0 and wlan2 have ip address in same subnet which is causing a conflict ? How about setting camera and eth0 as 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 ?

Comment: @migrc Also, iwconfig shows that wlan2 is connected to the access point. wlan2     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ACT"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 64:D9:55:F1:26:85 Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm Retry  long limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-26 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:16   Missed beacon:0

Comment: I think that using other network for the camera is the best solution (10.0.0.2 as you suggested, for example)  Other option is deleting the entry for eth0 in the route table ( with the previoia command using eth0 instead of wlan2) and then the command: route add 192.168.1.20 gateway 192.168.1.190 dev eth0